# Where does the expression “green wave” come from?

Tags: etymology, expressions

"[Green wave](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_wave)" is an idiomatic  expression used in traffic circulation that refers to:

> A green wave occurs when a series of traffic lights (usually three or more) are coordinated to allow continuous traffic flow over several intersections in one main direction.

[image]

(Wikipedia)

[image]

(wordpress.com)

Curiously the same expression is used also in [other languages](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_light_control_and_coordination) such as Italian “onda verde”, French, “vague verte”, Spanish “ola verde”, German "grüne Welle" and Dutch  "groene golf".

Where does “green wave” come from. Was it originally a foreign expression adopted by English speaking countries, or was it coined in English and then spread abroad?

Comment: That’s called “Timed traffic lights”

Comment: I usually just call it _green wave_. [So does Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_wave) I don’t know where the expression originated, but the same metaphor is used in all the localised versions of the Wikipedia article that I can decipher (don’t know about the Hebrew one). The opposite is also used: a _red wave_ is that annoying thing where every traffic light turns red right before you get to it. Do you have a specific reason not to want to use that?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: The title of the Hebrew article, גל ירוק (roughly /gal ja'rok/ in IPA), also literally means "(a) green wave".

Comment: Not that I've heard the term before, but I can't see it as coming from anything other than a direct allusion to a real wave (on water; audio signal)... your animated GIF clearly shows a slow moving wave pattern _/‾\\_/‾\\_ where the lucky driver hits the troughs as they're green ("_a green wave_") and an unlucky driver will he the peaks as they're red ("_a red wave_").

Comment: @TripeHound - I agree, the metaphor is clear, but it must have started somewhere by someone. And the fact that the same metaphor is used internationally, makes the issue even more intriguing in my opinion.

Comment: I must say, as someone who grew up in Southern California when synchronization of traffic lights was much in the news, and who lives now in Washington, where the failure of the computer that manages the timing of traffic lights in one of the suburban counties was also much in the news, that I have *never* heard the term *green wave* until just now, nor seen it in print. I always just said *the lights are synced* or *the lights are timed* in this or that region.

Comment: In the German Wikipedia article about the _grüne Welle_ (_green wave_) it states that the first manually controlled green wave was in Salt Lake City in 1917. It was followed in 1926 by a manually controlled green wave in Berlin. The Wikipedia article does not mention the origin of "_grüne Welle_" but it would not surprise me if other languages borrowed the German term in translation.

Comment: TIL that "Green Wave" is the nickname for the Tulane University sports teams. Also TIL that traffic signals were legislated into New York state in the 1930s, which I sort of knew because in the old movies, they used to have a human traffic cop directing traffic at busy intersections.

Comment: I concur that "green wave" is a European term. The top three scholarly hits I've gotten are in Italy, Denmark, and Hungary. The earliest I've found so far is UK 1991.

Comment: Through Ngram, I've found a couple of references to "green wave" in connection to traffic flow from 1956: [Green wave traffic study for the Boulevard Royal in Luxembourg](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vpnVAAAAMAAJ&q=%22green+wave+traffic%22&dq=%22green+wave+traffic%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8yoq8_a3cAhWhKcAKHfNgAi8Q6AEIKTAA) and [International Road Safety and Traffic Review](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uW3VAAAAMAAJ&q=%22green+wave%22&dq=%22green+wave%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIjIis_K3cAhXGN8AKHXLlD4oQ6AEILjAB) but with only snippets, there's not a lot of information to go on.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen "green wave" in English, but I had seen "grüne Welle" in German, probably as far back as the 1970's.

Comment: It's worth noting that the "obvious" wave effect in the gif above *would only be obvious to the system administrators*. There's no visible "wave" effect or appearance from the perspective of the commuters themselves. It started among urban planners & co. wherever it began, rather than as a colloquial thing among the drivers.

Comment: Add even slavic languages to the list. In Czech (and also in Slovak) it is 'zelená vlna', literal translation is again 'green wave'. We even have a traffic radio shows called Zelená vlna

Comment: Not too often, but I've heard traffic engineers and town planners talking about "phased traffic lights" since about 1960, and never with any expression that would come close to “green wave”. Hardly surprising because "wave" doesn't strike my ear as either analogous or poetic… I think “green stream/river/flow/row…” would all work better and to me that suggests if "green wave" really is ubiquitous, that’s because it spread from a single source; not because of independent evolution in dozens of countries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The earliest use I could find in English of 'green wave', with the sense of "coordinated traffic signals", ascribes the origin of the phrase to Germany, and refers to streetcar railway operations in 1927 Chicago:

> Other interesting features of the Chicago operation were the famous *co-ordinated traffic signal system — we say in Germany the Green wave"*…
>
> [*Electric Railway Journal*, January 14, 1928, p 95](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.d0000795989;view=1up;seq=121;size=175).

Comment: Nicely found - I found earlier references to "grune Welle" in German, but nothing to do with transport.

Comment: I too remember this from when I lived for a time in Germany in the '70s. I hadn't heard it in the U.S., but I felt entitled to translate it to my country and still use it today. Most Americans find it an odd usage, and some require explanation for what ought to be perfectly obvious.

Answer (score 2):

> "the term [Green wave](https://www.revolvy.com/page/Green-wave) has also been applied to railroad travel. For several years starting in the 1960s, the German Federal Railway maintained an advertising campaign featuring the slogan garantiert **grüne Welle** (Guaranteed **Green Wave**), *which communicated the notion of speed, limited delays and open track blocks to potential customers choosing between train and automobile travel, and was featured prominently in promotional materials ranging from posters to radio jingles."*

(www.revolvy.com)

> "**[Henry A. Barnes](https://www.revolvy.com/main/index.php?s=Henry%20Barnes%20(traffic%20engineer))** (December 16, 1906 – September 1968) was **an American traffic engineer and commissioner** who served in many cities, including Flint, Michigan; Denver, Colorado; Baltimore, Maryland; and New York City. Barnes *was responsible for many innovations in applied traffic engineering, including the Green Wave of coordinated traffic signals*..."

(www.revolvy.com)

> "[During 1965](http://www.fpz.unizg.hr/traffic/index.php/PROMTT/article/download/779/632/), there was a substantial increase in
>   the application of signalling systems in Croatia, since
>   the company "Nikola Tesla" started to use their own
>   capacities to develop and produce the devices for independent,
>   detecting and co-ordinated control.
>   In 1965, the first "green wave" (phased traffic
>   lights) was installed along the Brace Kavurica Street,
>   controlling traffic by the devices produced in the
>   above mentioned company. The exchange which coordinated
>   the operation of devices was installed in the
>   police building in Dordiceva street. By extending the
>   zone to the two neighbouring directions, two "green
>   waves" (phased traffic lights) were formed in the opposite
>   direction. The main exchange was moved to
>   Marticeva Street. Today, there is a new microprocessing
>   zone exchange which controls all the local
>   signalling devices in the city centre. "

(www.fpz.unizg.hr/traffic)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @user070221! I'm still very new to StackExchange...and lazy to boot :)

Comment: The site, revolvy, copies a lot of  their material from Wikipedia. Luckily, they do cite their sources, but the two excerpts you quoted are directly from Wikipedia. EDIT. No, after checking some other articles, Revolvy just copies everything from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S.:

**Signal Timing** [U.S. dept. of Transportation](https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/publications/publicroads/02janfeb/timing.cfm)

Managing Traffic Flow Through **Signal Timing**
by S. Lawrence Paulson

> It's a commuter's dream: The avenue is thick with traffic, but green
>   lights appear with regularity. Traffic flows smoothly, and lane
>   changing is minimal. Tailgating is rare. When a red light does appear,
>   no one tries to sneak through. Driving seems almost ... civilized.
>
> It sounds like a miracle, but it may just be another success story
>   resulting from traffic signal management, one of the most
>   cost-effective ways of keeping traffic moving smoothly and making
>   streets safer.
>
> Traffic signal management can be defined as using improved tools,
>   techniques, and equipment to make existing traffic signal control
>   systems operate more efficiently.

In Am spoken English typically called **traffic light synchronization**. Green wave appears to be of Eu origin.  I could find no expression origin.

Answer (score -2):

**Each country developed the phrase independently.**

Language adaptations come from the environment of which the language is spoken. And the internetz has proven how adaptive our language is.

After motor vehicle transport becoming an international norm; whose to say that the luck of riding a green wave would not present itself?

Each country has coastal exposure giving ground to have a word to describe the movement of a wave and a green light is the universal colour to communicate continuing traffic movement.

Given those circumstances I do not think it necessary that the phrase had to have physical vectors of people who used the phrase to spread, but it was possible to independently develop the phrase as the culture had already pollinated via the spread of transport technology.

Long shot. A fun concept to ponder. I look forward to hearing the answer.

Comment: Since I dislike people down-voting without bothering to explain, to me that would have sounded tenuous as a Comment, let alone an Answer.